# Karma-Jasmine Testing execution error HeadlessChrome

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to test my chart component and I am getting following error:

> HeadlessChrome 64.0.3240 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR   Disconnected, because
>   no message in 60000 ms. HeadlessChrome 64.0.3240 (Linux 0.0.0):
>   Executed 0 of 416 DISCONNECTED (1 min 0.007 secs / 0 secs)
>   HeadlessChrome 64.0.3240 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR HeadlessChrome 64.0.3240
>   (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 416 DISCONNECTED (1 min 0.007 secs / 0
>   secs)

I don't know what the problem is. What I am doing wrong?

I am using the chart component as shared component in different other components.

```
class MockService{

  public loadChartData(data: DataItem, date: Date ): Observable<any> {
    return of([])
  }

}

fdescribe('ChartRenderComponent', () => {
  let component: ChartRenderComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ChartRenderComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MoreComponentsModule, //this are PrimeNg components
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule
      ],
      declarations: [ChartRenderComponent],
      providers:[ {provide:TestService, useClass:MockService}]

    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ChartRenderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {

    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Which version of jasmine-core are you using?